# OpenLayers 2 cluster map convert from WMS to OSM

Tags: openlayers-2, jquery

I have implemented a simple OpenLayers map to plot stores on the map. I've done this using a WMS.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7n42uaux/3/

Now I want to use OpenStreetMap(OSM) maps.

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
```

When I do change it, the map gets drawn but the clusters don't get plotted properly. They are all shown as a summation and in the wrong location in the map.

Comment: the fiddle does not appear to work...

Comment: that's just because of the missing CSS-rule for the map container (add something like  #map { height:500px;}  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an internal and external projection for your GeoJSON-Format:

```
var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
  'internalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
  'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
});
```

just have a look at my version of your example:
http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/gmy0rpam/

Comment: can you help me  adding full screen control ? im facing issues http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172119/open-layers-map-full-screen-option-not-working/172122#172122