# OpenLayers Map Full Screen Option Not working

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to add a full screen option in my map implemented using OpenLayers. I tried adding it with:

```
var map1 = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: 'map',
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857") ,
        controls: OpenLayers.control.defaults().extend([
        new OpenLayers.control.FullScreen()
        ]),       
    });
```

and also by adding:

```
map1.addControl(new OpenLayers.control.FullScreen());
```

But it didn't work.

here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/gmy0rpam/

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing OpenLayers 2 and 3 here. There is no fullscreen control in version 2.